# Maven 3.0.4 error on Windows 8 x64: Usage: java [-options] class [args...]

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, maven, maven-3

This is my first post on this forum. I have a problem with Maven 3. OS: Windows 8 Professional RTM.

If I run any maven command (whatever) I always get the following answer:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)
>
> where options include:
>       -server       to select the "server" VM
>       -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
>                     The default VM is server.
>
> ```
> -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
> -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>               A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>               and ZIP archives to search for class files.
> -D<name>=<value>
>               set a system property
> -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
>               enable verbose output
> -version      print product version and exit
> -version:<value>
>               require the specified version to run
> -showversion  print product version and continue
> -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
>               include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
> -? -help      print this help message
> -X            print help on non-standard options
> -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               enable assertions
> -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               disable assertions
> -esa | -enablesystemassertions
>               enable system assertions
> -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
>               disable system assertions
> -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
>               load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
>                 see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
> -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
>               load native agent library by full pathname
> -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
>               load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
>
> -splash:<imagepath>
>               show splash screen with specified image
> ```

I used Google and forum search but the only results were a different problem: it was a problem on environment variables (most of them ending the path with an additional slash).

If I execute java -version I get:

> java version "1.6.0_35" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_35-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

If I execute javac -version I get:

> javac 1.6.0_35

The Maven verssion I am using is 3.0.4. These are the environment variables I added (I added M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME because I am not sure about which one is the right variable):

```
CATALINA_OPTS=%MAVEN_OPTS%
CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\src.zip;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
M2_HOME=d:\software\apache-maven-3.0.4
MAVEN_HOME=d:\software\apache-maven-3.0.4
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;d:\software\eclipse;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

The path environment variable has more paths but I just pasted here the paths I added for my final year project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So if you execute `mvn -version` you get the same output as if you execute `java` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right: It doesn't matter the option, I will receive the same lines than running "java" command. Any mvn command retunrs all those lines. But if I execute "java -version" I got the java version as I described in my post. Any idea?

Comment: Can you run `where mvn.bat` from command line ? I have a feeling that your maven installation is corrupted in some way.

Comment: I ran that command and I received the right path: d:\software\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\mvn.bat
And I downloaded Maven again and I uncompressed it again with the same result.

Comment: Ok, one more thing to check. Navigate to `apache-maven-3.0.4\bin` folder and run `mvn.bat -version` from there.

Comment: That's weird because it returns the Maven verssion: it seems my system doesn't see the mvn command despite environment variables are ok. Here you are the answer for the command you told me:

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: d:\software\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_35, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows nt (unknown)", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: I can only think of the following: 1) remove `MAVEN_HOME` variable, it's not needed (both from env and from `PATH`); 2) reboot your PC.

Comment: M2_HOME is not required for Maven 3.x

Comment: So... MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME both are not required for Maven 3? If so, how does the system find my Maven folder?

Edit: I just removed M2_HOME from environment and from PATH and it works now. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Keep `M2_HOME` and remove `MAVEN_HOME` (see instructions [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html)).

Comment: I replaced `MAVEN_HOME` with `M2_HOME` and it still works. Thanks @AndrewLogvinov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only environment variables you need to set are:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
MAVEN_HOME=D:\software\apache-maven-3.0.4
PATH=%PATH%;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Note, use D: instead of d:

Comment: Ok, thank you! But I thought that Windows is not case sensitive. I will change it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I use apache-maven-3.3.1 and see the same problem with Alberto
I tested and found that the error may happen when you run command on directory like: "C:\" "D:\" "E:\"... Should go to at lease 1 folder like: "D:\TestApp"

Comment: Unbeliveable. This was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

```
>I found that Maven cannot accept the JVM >property 
>
>
>"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=P:\"
>
>when it's value is the root folder of a device.
```

Any directory other than c:\ as the current directory and now...

```
mvn -v works.
```

Comment: Please keep you answers to just the answer, not commentary about how you reached it. We want to keep StackOverflow to just questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35"`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. That is the JAVA_HOME environment variable value I set (is the third one of the variables I pasted). Any other idea? :(

Comment: M2_HOME is not required for Maven 3.x

Comment: I just removed M2_HOME from environment and from PATH and it works now. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder P:\projects.

I ran mvn inside that folder. mvn ran as expected.

I changed directory to P:\ to run mvn. mvn blurted out the error with the java usage advisory as depicted in this question.

I found, by tearing the mvn.bat apart, that Maven cannot accept the JVM property

> "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=P:\"

when it's value is the root folder of a device.

I have not tried in Linux yet.

*BTW, I also found that mvn has an error message that has a bad spelling. The error message is "multiModuleProjectDirectory **propery** not defined". At first I had dyslexically read, "multiModuleProjectDirectory not **properly** defined."*