# Maven not picking up its own environment variable

Tags: maven

I extracted maven to a directory.

Set the system environment variable M2_HOME to the location of the directory. Then I added %M2_HOME%\bin to my path variables.

However maven complains thaat m2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.

This surely should be impossible considering it would have to USE M2_HOME to call mvn in the first place!!?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29870792/3790806

Comment: Tried all of those, no help. Thats why I made this post

Comment: How did you set M2_HOME and what exact value did you use?

Comment: did it in environment variables, the odd thing is when I check set with commandline, its all correct!

Comment: FYI, ensure that you open a new command prompt or restart your IDE so the environment variables are loaded.

Comment: It finally corrected itself and I have no idea why.... odd as hell. Because I tried everything you guys said before.