# Maven Setup Error

Tags: java, maven

I've just downloaded `Maven 3.3.9`

My variables are:

```
M2_HOME  C:\Users\apragnya\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9 

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

and my PATH

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\%JAVA_HOME%\bin%M2%%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin;C:\Users\apragnya\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

I get this error:

```
 C:\Users\apragnya>mvn -version 

 ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory. M2_HOME = "C:\Users\apragnya\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9" 
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of the Maven installation
```

Comment: restart cmd after changeing the variables.

Comment: Change `M2_HOME` to point : `C:\Users\apragnya\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin`

Comment: Check this question [Maven M2\_HOME set to an invalid directory (Windows 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034052/maven-m2-home-set-to-an-invalid-directory-windows-7)