# M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: windows, maven, path

I know this question has been asked before, but no previously visited threads helped.

I downloaded and unzipped a maven folder in a directory on my drive, added the `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` environment variables as shown here:

[image: M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME]

I also added their \bin to the path variable as shown in this picture.
[image: Path variable]

but then when I try to test it in a cmd window via `mvn -version` it gives me this error:
[image]

Mind you, when I do `cd %M2_HOME%\bin` and then `mvn -version` it works... So what am I missing here?

For info, I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034052/maven-m2-home-set-to-an-invalid-directory-windows-7

Comment: @Tunaki like I said, I visited that thread, and I have downloaded the right maven folder _which contains bin, boot, conf, lib folders_, and like I said, when I open a cmd in the bin folder and use `mvn -version` it works.

Comment: It is normal that it works since the `mvn` executable is the same directory. M2_HOME, you don't even need to set. You do need the path to the bin folder added to PATH.

Comment: @Tunaki look at the screens, the bin folder HAS been added to PATH...

Comment: I do not see the pictures... this is why you need to post text.

Comment: @Tunaki " **I also added their \bin to the path variable as shown in this picture.** "

Comment: Did you close and restart your console?

Comment: Yes, and let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122767/discussion-between-aetos-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the version was just a bad one... I downloaded and used aoache-maven-3.0.4 and it worked perfectly.